# Javascript simple animation loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am new to javascript, and trying to learn the basics before jumping to jQuery and all the other libraries, so I can understand what's going on (or be able to even try)
I have tried to run a simple animation with a for loop, activated by onclick. There is a single div (id=demo), 4 classes of CSS for the div (up, down, left, right, all modifing the position:relative) and I want to make it move in a square motion.

```
<div id="demo" class="left" onclick="initElemAnim()"
```

css

```
#demo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: 2s linear;
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    }

  #demo.right {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
  }

  #demo.left {
    position: relative;
    left:0px;
  }
  #demo.down {
    position: relative;
    top:200px;
  }
  #demo.up {
    position: relative;
    bottom:200px;
  }
```

js

```
var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
  var useMe = ["right", "down", "left", "up"];
  var i = 0;

  function initElemAnim() {
    for (; i < 4; ) {
      elem.className = useMe[i];
      setTimeout(i+=1, 2000);
    }
}
```

Link to code http://jsbin.com/holusevedo/1/watch?html,css,js,output

What happens after I click is - the red square disappears.

What is wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Please put your code here, rather than a link to it.

Comment: Check your css classes - you're moving it up out of view when you click.

Comment: note that `setTimeout(i+=1, 2000);` seems strange, the first argument is supposed to be a function. Also, all timeouts execute at the same time

Comment: the first class is "right" - 200px to the right, so it shouldnt be up.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is async so it does not halt the code (there is no "sleep" in js) so your for loop would basically loop indefinetely. You can use `setInterval()` and then `clearInterval()` to stop, or read up on recursion http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/ . If you want to try the more modern way, try googling for "requestAnimationFrame"

Comment: You need `setTimeout(function(){i+=1;}, 2000);` - setTimeout takes a function, not a statement.

Comment: @xec thanks for the answer! so basically what youre saying - setTimeout does not wait the period of time before executing? ever?

Comment: see [this](http://jsbin.com/vawuhopore/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: @Rambo it waits, but in this case the loop would spawn four functions with the same 2000ms delay, so all would finish at basically the same time. You could also use `setTimeout( fn, 2000 * i )` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set bot `left` and `top` for every point in the animation, otherwise going from the "left" step to "down" the element will move diagonally to the bottom-left corner (because `.down` doesn't have `left` property, so the browser animates `top` to 200px and `left` to 0).

Then your loop starts all the timeouts at the same moment, so all the class changes will execute after two seconds and the only class name on the element will be from whichever timeout has finished last. You should use `setInterval`.

CSS

```
#demo.tl {
  left:0;
  top:0
}

#demo.tr {
  top:0;
  left:200px;
}

#demo.br {
  left:200px;
  top:200px;
}
#demo.bl {
  top:200px;
  left:0;
}
```

JS:

```
 var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
 var useMe = ["tr", "br", "bl", "tl"];
 var i = 0;

  function initElemAnim() {
    setInterval(function(){
      // this function executes every 2000ms, 
      // setting the class name then incrementing the counter
      // or going back to 0 if it reaches the last class name
      elem.className = useMe[i];
      i = i < 3 ? i+1 : 0;
    }, 2000);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/holusevedo/3/watch?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

As `i` is a global variable, you can do like this:

```
  function initElemAnim() {
      if(i==3)i=0;
      elem.className = useMe[i++];
   }

setInterval(initElemAnim, 4000);
```

`setTimeout` only call the function once, while `setInterval` called function every time meets the time period.So that you can loop the 4 classes.

Answer (score 0):

change your css to

```
 #demo {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transition: 1s linear;
position:relative;
margin-left: 0px;
}

#demo.right,#demo.down {
margin-left: 200px;
}

#demo.left {
margin-left:0px;
}
#demo.down,#demo.left {
margin-top:200px;
}
#demo.up {
margin-top:0px;

}
```

and your script to

```
var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
  var useMe = ["right", "down", "left", "up"];
  var interval;

  function initElemAnim() {
  var i = 0;
    elem.className = useMe[i];
    interval = setInterval(function(){ 
            if(i < 4){
            i = i + 1;
            elem.className = useMe[i];
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
}
```

use setInterval() instead of setTimeout().